# Line break when submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue with my chat bot app where a line break is being inserted into the form after the user is pressing the submit button. To clarify, the message **is** being sent, but then creating a line break so the user has to backspace for the form to be completely empty.

```
var enableEnterKey = function() {
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if($('#maxx-message-box').is(':focus') && e.keyCode === 13) {
        var message = $('#maxx-message-box').val();
        sendMessage(message);
    }
});
```

This is our function. Please help.

Comment: I don't see where you are clearing the input box after sending a message in the code you posted

Comment: [`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) should block newline addition

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev That's exactly what i needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like:

```
$("#maxx-message-box").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
    var message = $("#maxx-message-box").val().replace(/\n/g, "");
    if (!!message)
    {
        sendMessage(message);
        $("#maxx-message-box").val("");
    }
    return false;
});
```